# .Net Core - Can't get any reference assembly's controller action when used framework netcoreapp2.2

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a core project named `Test.Web`, its csproj content like below:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\TestWeb.Infrastructure\TestWeb.Infrastructure.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

It reference a external assembly named `TestWeb.Infrastructure`,and its csproj content like below:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Ok, the `TestWeb.Infrastructure` have a get action in `TestController` like below:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace TestWeb.Infrastructure.Controllers
{
    public class TestController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Fire()
        {
            return Content("Hello!!!!!");
        }
    }
}
```

Then I started to run the `Test.Web` project and request to `https://localhost:5001/Test/Fire`, the response gave me 404 not found..., so I 
add `Version="2.2.0"` to Microsoft.AspNetCore.App in `TestWeb.Infrastructure` csproj file within `ItemGroup` section like below

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.2.0"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

And ran the site to request `https://localhost:5001/Test/Fire` again, it gave me the content `Hello!!!!!`, but when I changed the Version to another like 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.3 etc. It would throw other error(NU1605) when build.

My question is why can I successfully execute only when setting the version number to 2.2.0? My used .net core sdk is `2.2.105`

I make a demo at here: https://github.com/linmasaki/TestWeb/tree/master

Comment: How is your routing set up?

Comment: My route is set by default, I consider is not route problem.

Comment: Your setup is all kinds of confused. You don't need a project reference to make an HTTP request. In fact, one web project should virtually never depend on another. I cannot think of a single reason you would need to. If there's some functionality that you need to shared, that should be done via a class library.

Comment: This is a simple scenario, In real case I have a lot of external assembly didn't include in the main web project at start, some controller class would separate from the main project.

Comment: Try to explicitly adding the library as an application part in your startup`services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2).AddApplicationPart(typeof(TestWeb.Infrastructure.Controllers.TestController).Assembly);`Refer to https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/8095

Comment: @Xing Zou Yes, I know this is one of workarounds, but my main problem is why not need to do this before version 2.2.0.

Comment: @Xing Zou When I add some other reference project in main project's .csproj, it will add to `PartManger.ApplicationParts` by default, but after version 2.2.1 it won't.